# Soap Endpoints with ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, api, asp.net-core, soap

Currently I have only worked with REST and setting my endpoints directly in the Controller.

For example:

```
[HttpGet("someEndpoint")]
```

Now I have to work with SOAP and I'm trying to set the endpoint in my `Program.cs` (see screenshot). I'm always getting an error for the `BasicHttpBinding()`.

My question: do I have to set the endpoints in the controller? The same way I'm doing it with my normal REST API? I didn't find an answer for this on the Internet. Thank you very much in advance.

(My native language is German, sorry for my English :) )

[image: Error]

EDIT: the code:

```
using SoapCore;
using System.ServiceModel;
using WebAPI_2023.Models;
using WebAPI_2023.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddSoapCore();
builder.Services.AddScoped<CalculatorService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISampleService, SampleService>();
builder.Services.AddControllers();

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseSoapEndpoint<ISampleService>("/Service.asmx", new 
BasicHttpBinding(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

EDIT 2 : I found my error.Now it works perfectly :)

```
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
endpoints.UseSoapEndpoint<ISampleService>("/Service.asmx", new 
SoapEncoderOptions(), SoapSerializer.XmlSerializer);

});
```

Comment: Please don´t add images of code. They can´t be copied and tested and the code is barely readable.

Comment: Hey sorry just saw the image is really small. I added the code :)

Comment: You have to add service reference and endpoint to your asp.net core project connected service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to set the Endpoints in the Controller? The same way im
> doing it with my normal REST API´s? I didnt find an answer for this on
> the Internet

Well, for `Web Service` integration within the `asp.net core project` regardless of version there are two [`prerequisite`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide#how-to-use-the-extension):

**Prerequisite:**

1. Either your [`web service`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/visualstudio/csharp/language-compilers/write-web-service#consume-a-web-service) must be running and `URL` should available for calling
2. Or must have Valid `WSDL` file in local machine.

**Common Implementation For Both:**

Following steps would be same for both `asmx` and `wsdl` integration.

In addition, please be sure that, I have used `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022`
`Version 17.3.6` while preparing this answer.

***Step:1***

[image]

***Step:2***

[image]

***Step:3***

[image]

**Implementation Using asmx URL:**

[image]

**Note:** If your `Web Service` up and running it will start adding the reference without any issue.

**Implementation Using WSDL file:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** You should `select path` for your `valid wsdl file` here. Ignore my files here, you outght to choose your `wsdl file` instead.

**Use Your Service Inside Your Web API/MVC Controller**

Now, In your Web API project, you could use a service reference added earlier. Like below

Please note that, you should call the method according to the WCF service's method.

```
        var serviceReference1 = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client();
        var result = await serviceReference1.GetDataAsync(1) ;
```

[image]

If you still encounter any further issue for integration you could [`refer to our official document for more details here`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/wcf-web-service-reference-guide#how-to-use-the-extension)

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. Its not exactly what is was looking for. But i found the error and changed this line of my code. I added it in my edit.

Comment: You are welcome and glad to assist you.